# MRR -setting transparent color (MapInfo)

Tags: mapinfo, ssa, multi-resolution-raster

In Mapinfo Advanced 16

I tried to merge all the 2016/10cm, 2014/15cm and 2011/50cm separately into mrr (works fine) and then to merge these three together. It started to process but (3 days) later MI crashed. Even if it did work I am afraid I would get the no imagery areas on the higher rez file (higher resolution doesn't cover the whole area) as white over the lower rez (covering the whole area).

What can I do to at least view these three datasets in mapinfo without the white -the usual way of setting the transparent color doesn't work on the mrr's.

Properties in MRR file

[image]

10cm imagery over 50cm

[image]

50cm imagery without 10cm imagery
[image]
disregard the white no-data area, that tile was missing from our project.

What can I do -the end result should be a highest rez possible mrr or a mapinfo workspace with each layer seperately not showing the areas with no data. This is for use in SSA so I am not (to) worried by the file size as it will get tiled.

Comment: BTW, you ought to move the question of number of files when merging into a MRR to a new thread. You should only have one question

Comment: Ok -it's how I got to this issue so solving it would also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapInfo Pro tries to guess which colour should be transparent in some cases. When it does so, it put in a specific Raster Style line in the tab file to prevent the user from changing this.

Try to open the tab file for your MRR in a text editor.
It will look like this:

```
!table
!version 300
!charset WindowsLatin1

Definition Table
  File "hav110cm_960.tif"
  Type "RASTER"
  (439996.5,6410005.5) (0,0) Label "Pt 1",
  (871258.5,6410005.5) (47918,0) Label "Pt 2",
  (871258.5,6063118.5) (47918,38543) Label "Pt 3",
  (439996.5,6063118.5) (0,38543) Label "Pt 4"
  CoordSys Earth Projection 8, 115, "m", 9, 0, 0.9996, 500000, 0
  Units "m"
  RasterStyle 4 1
  RasterStyle 7 16777215
  RasterStyle 9 1
begin_metadata
"\IsReadOnly" = "FALSE"
"\MapInfo" = ""
"\MapInfo\TableID" = "21358ed5-59da-417d-9e9d-0a2d2a147cc8"
end_metadata
```

The line you are looking for is:

```
RasterStyle 9 1
```

If you remove this line from the tab file and reopen the file in MapInfo Pro, the *Select Colour* option in the *Adjust Image Styles* dialog will be enabled.

Comment: Horsebell Moller - Works perfectly, thanks. My other question was the MI Advanced merge function to mrr have a limit on the number of files it will merge?

Comment: No limit that I know of. I have merged thousands of files in one go.

Answer (score 2):

This limitation will no longer exist in MapInfo Pro 17.0.

so by default the "RasterStyle 9 1" tag will not be present (even if it is it won't have any impact) in next version of MapInfo Pro.